# Make a landscape page on the next available page (without blank space)

Tags: spacing, graphics, page-breaking, landscape, lscape

I am using `lscape` to include a figure in the middle of my text on a landscape page. However, instead of breaking to the landscape page at the point where I start the `landscape` environment, I would like to simply have the figure appear automatically on the *next available page*. Here's an illustration.

Right now, my document looks like this:

[image: Large blank space at end of first paragraph on first page, second page is figure, third page is full.]

I want it to look like this (for the image, I split up my text above and below the `landscape` environment manually, which is not desirable):

[image: Text flows to the bottom of page one and resumes at the next word after the figure on page three.]

Here is the source for the document (the first image shown above):

```tex
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,graphicx,lscape}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.50cm]{geometry}
\title{LOREM IPSUM: Typography's Most Useless Phrase}
\author{Concerningly Angered Typographists' Symposium (CATS)}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...
    
    \begin{landscape}
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{/tmp/cat123.jpg}
            \caption{These cats all know that lorem ipsum is Latin jargon. \\ \textbf{Attribution:} \\ {\footnotesize By Alvesgaspar - Top left: File:Cat August 2010-4.jpg by AlvesgasparTop middle: File:Gustav chocolate.jpg by Martin BahmannTop right: File:Orange tabby cat sitting on fallen leaves-Hisashi-01A.jpg by HisashiBottom left: File:Siam lilacpoint.jpg by Martin BahmannBottom middle: File:Felis catus-cat on snow.jpg by Von.grzankaBottom right: File:Sheba1.JPG by Dovenetel, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=17960205}}
        \end{figure}
    \end{landscape}

    Nam dui ligula...
\end{document}
```

Comment: don't use `landscape` you want a float so use `sidewaysfigure` from `rotating` package

Comment: `sidewaysfigure` breaks `hyperref`, by the way.

Comment: huh?...........

Comment: Sorry. I meant that when you try to use `autoref` to reference a `sidewaysfigure`, it gives you the section number reference instead (as if the `label` was written right below `section`, `subsection`, etc. and not in the figure itself). Do I need to put a `figure` environment inside of the `sidewaysfigure` environment to prevent this?

Comment: seems to be a different question, you could ask on this site or if you think it's a bug raise it at github, either way with a complete small example.

Comment: For anyone having that problem: I fixed it by moving `label` below everything else. It wasn't working because `label` was at the beginning of the `sidewaysfigure` environment, not the end.